# Django-rest-auth: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to use django-rest-auth password reset feature but after a post request at `/rest-auth/password/reset/` i get the error stated in the title ([Traceback](http://dpaste.com/3P8TFQR)) and i don't understand why. I followed the installation procedure from the documentation page. My `urls.py` is:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
```

I also added the required apps in `settings.py`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved by adding

```
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from rest_auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView

re_path(r'^rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
            name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

to urlpatterns in `urls.py` . This way you will obtain a reset link in the mail like: `../password/reset/confirm/uid/token`. In order to complete the procedure you must send a POST request to `../password/reset/confirm/` with this body:

```
{
    "new_password1": "",
    "new_password2": "",
    "uid": "",
    "token": ""
}
```

Comment: This started giving me error as `"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."`

Comment: I'm using a jwt token auth system not a session one

Comment: Hi, since the token and user id is in email, how do we get those in our app

Comment: what will be the uid parameter here? If I put the one i received in email, it says invalid uid. please help

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns += [
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),

    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_confirm.html"),
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```